# Where can I find a golden ant?

Tags: frogatto-and-friends

In the *secluded hut* area, you find a 'mole' living in a house on top of a hill.  He has a collection of ants, but he tells you he's missing the rare 'golden ant' and asks if you would bring one back to him.

I've been back and forward a couple screens and haven't seen anything but regular ants (as far as I can tell).  What does the golden ant look like?  And where can I find one?

[image: The mole wants me to find one]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's one in Burn and Bubble, three levels west of Secluded Hut.

[image: Golden Ant]

Comment: Thanks!  Little tricky to get it out of that stage, but I managed.  The reward was worth it! ;]